# Is Turkish coffee grinding finer than Espresso grinding?

Tags: coffee, grinding, turkish-cuisine

I am shopping for an electric grinder that can grind to the extremely fine grind of **Turkish coffee**.

But the only commercially available electric grinders I have found so far refer to Espresso coffee (as if manufacturers never heard of Turkish coffee...)

So it is very tempting for me to settle for an Espresso type of grinder but really what I need is any grinder that could grind at least 8 Oz. of Turkish coffee at a time.

So... my question is simple: Does **Turkish coffee** grind:

1. Finer than Espresso grind?
2. Coarser than Espresso grind?
3. Same as Espresso grind?

Comment: Turkish coffee is finer than espresso grind. I don't think a regular (cheap) grinder could do it consistently.

Comment: @user5561 Thanks for this tip. I noticed that the machines in our supermarkets have a "Turkish Coffee" setting, but when I tried it, the result was very disappointing. My el-cheapo [Krups grinder](http://www.krupsusa.com/All+Products/Coffee+Grinders/Products/F203/F203.htm) grinds finer than that, but it is too small and very inconvenient (too much time scraping the coffee with an especially thin teaspoon).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes Turkish coffee grind is finer than esspresso grind.

Grinders are typically one of two kinds: Blade grinders, or burr mill/grinders. For a consistent turkish coffee or esspresso grind, it's recommended to get a [conical burr grinder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_preparation#Burr-grinding) they can produce the fine grind you need without heating up the coffee and losing flavor.  Also, the better ones tend to not 'click' as you adjust the grind size. That way you can calibrate your grinder to the specific bean roast without making big jumps in grind size.

If you are going for the whole 8 oz, i'd recommend giving the grinder a break to cool down part way and prevent the grind from getting too hot and essentially roasting again.

Comment: Thanks! I will probably be going for [this](http://www.capresso.com/coffee-grinders-burr-infinity.shtml) Conical Burr Grinder since it explicitly mentions Turkish coffee as one of its settings.

Comment: Reporting results: I first fell for this [Cuisinart® Supreme Grind™ Automatic Burr Mill](http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/1/3/cuisinart-burr-mill) because my local store didn't have Capress's model 560 in stock. This turned to be totally inadequate for Turkish coffee. Too coarse. To noisy. And reviews also claim that it breaks within months...

Comment: I then returned it and the store offered that the [Capresso Infinity 560](http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/product.asp?SKU=14902422) be shipped to my home. What an exquisite experience. Indeed, as it claims, it grinds to the finest level of Turkish coffee I have been used to. I am delighted!

Comment: @VeryObjective oh I've worked with that Cuisinart.  It's wholly inconsistent, and big jumps on the dial.  Glad you found one that works for you.

Answer (score 4):

Turkish coffee requires an extremely fine, powdery, flour-like grind, which is much finer than even a very finely grinding espresso grinder will produce. Grinding 8 oz quantities at a go really requires a commercial grinder, and even those, like the BUNN, require fitting with burrs designed for Turkish coffee. Commercial grinders will have heavier-duty motors capable of turning larger burrs that will both grind the coffee to the required fineness but also have enough mass to avoid overheating and affecting the taste of the ground product.

Answer (score 2):

Turkish coffee requires a stone mill. Not a burr mill. A stone mill, like the one that is used for making flour. It is rather expensive, very heavy and hard to find in countries where Turkish coffee is not popular (as in Turkey itself, Hellas and Arab countries). A burr mill, even a professional one with conical burrs, needs to be pushed to its very limits in order to make somewhat acceptable (drinkable) Turkish coffee.

Answer (score 2):

An old discussion, but others will come, as I just did, via a search. Grinding coffee very fine, to powder, as required for Turkish coffee, requires **more torque than is available with home grinders**; heavy-duty commercial grinders will do the job. If you don't want an expensive and large grinder, either buy coffee **ready-ground** for Turkish (keep it hermetically sealed in the freezer), or use a **Turkish hand grinder**; they are not expensive. Zassenhaus do a similar hand grinder, the Havanna (probably the only suitable Zassenhaus model), at a much higher price. I use a Turkish one; it works fine, but is laborious. I hear that some people grind coffee in a standard grinder, then regrind it in a Turkish mill so it requires much less effort.

Comment: I like your two step tip, re-grid in a hand mill.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has to be finer. For example I recently had to use a combination of a  Breville BCG450 conical burr grinder and a cheap blade mill to get it the right way. When the result is too fine for espresso, it is just right for Turkish .

Comment: Dear Kevin, I understand that you want to contribute, but we are not a discussion forum. We are a question-and-answer site, and new posts are expected to address the question literally. I had to edit your post considerably, because it got two flags as not being an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately, I have not encountered a grinder that can grind the coffee beans fine enough for Turkish coffee. It is perhaps more accurate to call it "to pound" instead of "to grind" when it comes to Turkish coffee. I think the best device for it is a mortar, a hand mill could als work.

Answer (score 0):

I have an expensive electric conical burr mill (from Cusineart) but for Turkish, I use my hand grinder.  As I am currently writing this in a Starbucks in the US, I asked one of the Baristas here and their grinders are from Europe and have a Turkish setting on them.  So I would advise, get a Turkish hand grinder or buy some beans from Starbucks and let them figure it out. - Kameal

Answer (score 0):

A hand cranked Turkish coffee grinder is the way to go, trust me.  Even if you have the cash to spend on a high-end electric burr grinder, the heat generated by the machine will have a negative effect on the taste of your coffee, comparable to a burnt aftertaste.  By the time you are getting into a cup of Turkish coffee in your own home, you are probably no novice to the coffee scene, and it would be a shame to ruin what could have been a fantastic cup of Turkish coffee just because you are trying to save time in the grind.  The entire process from selecting your beans, grinding, and brewing is a therapeutic tradition and should enjoyed in its entirety.  Not to mention the romantic element to a manual preparation, as opposed to trying to hold a conversation over an electric grinder.  Save your money and get a manual Turkish grinder. You'll taste the difference immediately.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Since you clearly have opinions about grinders, I thought I'd point out that the OP asked about whether Turkish grind was finer than an espresso grind, and you didn't include that in your answer.  Maybe edit it and add that information?